# Cannot find items from ArrayList?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I cannot seem to get my saved accounts stored inside my ArrayList. I think the latest one overwrites the oldest one, but I need them all to stack up in the ArrayList.

When I run the program, I create (add to ArrayList) a new Account, say Greg. Then I go on using that account and later on, add another account, say Bob. Then I click on "search for account" and type in Greg, it doesn't find it, but it finds Bob. HOWEVER, if I search for Greg BEFORE I create Bob, it FINDS IT!

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
////////// DECLARATIONS /////////
public static ArrayList dataStore;
public static int       index;
dataStore = new ArrayList(10);
index     = 0;

/////////////////////////////// ADD NEW ACCOUNT ////////////////////////////////
    else if(source.equals("Add new account")) {
//*************         Output
        accountName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the account name: ");
        account.setName(accountName);

        String strInitialBalance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your initial
        balance: ");
        initialBalance = Double.parseDouble(strInitialBalance);
        account.setBalance(initialBalance);

        account = new CheckingAccount(initialBalance, accountName);
        dataStore.add(index++, account);

    }

//////////////////////////////// FIND ACCOUNT /////////////////////////////////
    else if(source.equals("Find an account")) {
        String str, name;

        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Account name: ");

        for (int index = 0; index < dataStore.size(); index++) {
            Account datum = (Account)dataStore.get(index);

            if (str.equals(datum.getName())) {
                name = datum.getName();
                textArea.setText("Found Account for " + name);
            }
            else
                textArea.setText("No Accounts found!");

        } // for

    }
```

This "account" object they are referring to is a class I have where all the data gets stored. Here is its header:

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account implements Serializable {
// ...
// Methods
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your original chunk of code.

```
for (int index = 0; index < dataStore.size(); index++) {
        Account datum = (Account)dataStore.get(index);

        if (str.equals(datum.getName())) {
            name = datum.getName();
            textArea.setText("Found Account for " + name);
        }
        else
            textArea.setText("No Accounts found!");

    }
```

I dont think it makes sense to have the else statement inside your for loop, try the code below instead...

```
boolean found = false;
for (int index = 0; index < dataStore.size(); index++) {
        Account datum = (Account)dataStore.get(index);

        if (str.equals(datum.getName())) {
            name = datum.getName();
            textArea.setText("Found Account for " + name);
            found = true;
        }
    }
 if(!found){

     textArea.setText("No Accounts found!");
 }
```

I think that you don't want the `else{}` inside the `for(...) loop` because as you navigate through your data structure, many times, your initial `if (str.equals(datum.getName()))` statement will fail as you have not found the account yet. However, if you eventually find it, you will meet the `if(...)` condition and tell the user via `textArea` that you found the account. Then you set a `boolean` to true that you found it. If you go through the **ENTIRE** data structure and have not found it, the boolean will still equal false, and you will meet the condition for the second if which is  `if(!found)` after the for loop, and will tell the user that you have searched the entire data structure and have not found the account.

Also, I think your first else if should look more like the code below (I don't know what the method signatures look like for CheckingAccount so some of this is a guess on actual syntax)

```
else if(source.equals("Add new account")) {
//*************         Output
    //use constructor below if you have a default constructor aka no paramaters
    CheckingAccount account = new CheckingAccount();
    //now that you have object linked to account, you can use setters
    accountName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the account name: ");
    //set the name
    account.setName(accountName);

    String strInitialBalance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your initial
    balance: ");
    initialBalance = Double.parseDouble(strInitialBalance);
    //set the balance
    account.setBalance(initialBalance);

    //dont make a new object now as you did before..just add the object to your arraylist
    dataStore.add(index++, account);

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you are encountering? What is your input and your expected output? Consider adding that to the question.

Comment: I added more details in my question ^^^

Comment: Another potential problem I am seeing...you are using a variable in the first else if{} named account. You use setter methods on account, and then create a new object and assign the contents to account after you have already been using account as an object..

Comment: Yes but this else if() is part of a large IF statement, about 10 actions. Each one refers to a Menu Option

Comment: See question edit for reference as to what I was talking about

Comment: Yup, that did it! My problem was, I was not linking my account to an Object, instead I was using 1 object and just changing the values, THUS my overwriting issue. Thanks man!

Comment: Awesome! glad to help and glad it worked out for you! good luck programming